# Серая сетка вместо карты в React Native Yandex Map (Expo)

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, react-native, yandexmapkit, expo

Яндекс Карты в React Native Expo рендерятся, но отображается только серая сетка и логотип Яндекса снизу справа. Я установил пакет через `npm i react-native-yamap --save`, сделал `npx expo prebuild`, инициализировал карту в файле App.tsx `YaMap.init('API_KEY')` и запустил приложение через `npx expo run:android`. Сама компонента выглядит вот так `<YaMap style={{width: 250, height: 350}}/>`. В итоге карта в эмуляторе и в готовом APK Android отображается как серый квадрат с логотипом. API ключ в Яндексе активен, в проекте на чистом React-Native (без Expo) карта отображается без проблем, но в Expo почему-то серая сетка. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

[image: Скриншот из эмулятора]